# About TLS 1.2 support in openssl

Tags: openssl

Does openssl 1.0.1c (the latest stable version that I can find on the www.openssl.org) fully support TLS 1.2?

I have searched all the changelogs about openssl. Unfortunately, I can not find the information such as "fully support TLS 1.2". It just mentioned "Initial TLS v1.2 support" in the "changes between 1.0.0h and 1.0.1".

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

"Support TLS v1.2 and TLS v1.1." -- https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-notes.html

Comment: I doubt that it just initial support instead of fully support TLS 1.2. Because in the changelog (more detail than news), it just mentioned initial support.

Comment: What do you mean by "fully"?  I'm currently running a server that supports TLS 1.2 (via openssl), and I can connect to it with openssl.

Comment: eg, openssl 1.0.1c (the latest stable version) does not support "TLS 1.2 Suite B profile". Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TLS_Implementations#cite_note-renegotiation-28

Comment: It seems that the support for "TLS 1.2 suite B" will be added in the version 1.1 according to the changelog. Unfortunately 1.1 is not stable yet (The latest stable version from the openssl is 1.0.1c

Comment: The link is dead now

Comment: Relevant link now seems to be https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html , though that exact text has since aged off.