# Enable TLSv1.2 in apache 2.2.22

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I need to update apache 2.2.22 to support TLSv1.2. I have tried the below command but it is not working

```
SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1
```

But when I put this command it displays an error in windows event viewer

```
SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.2'
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 2):

Support for TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 [was added in httpd 2.2.23](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/CHANGES). You will need to upgrade httpd itself, and also have OpenSSL 1.0.1 available at build-time and at run-time.

Comment: For clarity, looking at the https://github.com/mozilla/server-side-tls/issues/62 post, it appears there is a confusion which Apache version introduced TLS 1.2 support. However, the change log posted above (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/CHANGES) states version 2.2.24.

Comment: @RZet There is no confusion. It was added in 2.2.23, but that version was never officially released and so the first official release to include it was 2.2.24. If you have 2.2.23 for some reason, then you have TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 support available (if built with a proper OpenSSL, of course).

Answer (score 1):

TLS for Apache is provided by OpenSSL. If TLS 1.2 is supported in your installation depends on the installed OpenSSL version, see [About TLS 1.2 support in openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032623/).

Judging from the [changelog](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html), you will need at least OpenSSL 1.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. You need OpenSSL 1.0.1 at least, and the API of OpenSSL 1.0.1 is not compatible with Apache 2.2.22. You will need to upgrade Apache HTTPD.

Comment: This is incorrect. Apache httpd 2.4 is not required to use TLSv1.1 and higher, nor is it required to use OpenSSL 1.0.1 and higher.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Thanks, amended.